# How to pass a http request result in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get the http request result to my child controller.

I have something like

```
<div ng-controller = "parentCtrl">
     <button ng-click="callApi()">click me</button>

     <div ng-controller = "childCtrl">
         <div>{{productDetail}}</div>
     </div>
</div>

angular.module('App').controller('parentCtrl', ['$scope','myFactory',
    function($scope, myFactory) {
        $scope.callApi = function() {
            myFactory.request(id)
                .then(function(data) {
                    $scope.productDetail = data
                    //do something in parent controller here....
                })

        }
    }
]);

angular.module('App').controller('childCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        //I am not sure how to get the productDetail data here since it's a http request call.
    }
]);



angular.module('App').factory('myFactory', function($http) {
    var service = {};

    service.request = function(id) {
        return createProduct(id)
            .then(function(obj) {
                productID = obj.data.id;
                return setProductDetail(productID)
            })
            .then(getDetail)
            .then(function(productDetail) {             
                return productDetail.data
            })          
    }
    var createProduct = function(id) {
        return $http.post('/api/product/create', id)
    }

    var setProductDetail = function(id) {
        return $http.post('/api/product/setDetail', id)
    }

    var getDetail = function() {
        return $http.get('/api/product/getDetail')
    }

    return service;
});
```

I was able to get the request result for my parentCtrl but I am not sure how to pass it to my child controller. Can anyone help me about it?

Thanks!

Comment: `childCtrl` has it automatically in its scope after the api call resolves and `parentCtrl` sets the scope variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potential approaches:

1) Inject myFactory into the child controller as well.

2) Access the parent scope directly from within childCtrl:

```
$scope.$parent.productDetail
```

3) If wanting to access from HTML

```
$parent.productDetail
```

Above assumes you are wanting to access that value specifically separate from a potential version on the child scope (existing code doesn't show that).

If it's a child scope, and nothing on the child scope (or a scope in between) is named productDetail, and you're not setting a primitive value in the child scope with that name, then you should be able to see the value directly through prototypical inheritance (but any of the three scenarios listed could force the need for a reference through the parent).

Comment: Thanks Mike, but $scope.$parent.productDetail and $parent.produtDetail will be undefined when the page first loaded because they are http request calls. Your first approach is doable but I feel like make same request in different scope is redundant +1 though

Comment: What behavior are you wanting? Obviously there won't be a value to show until something resolves. You can set $scope.productDetail = "" (or any other default value you want to display before the callApi() is triggered and the http call resolves). Again, this value would be available to all child scopes, and would be updated automatically by Angular when the promise resolves and productDetail is set in the parent controller.

Comment: Take a look at this Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/QXBPkqOfqdGmV6B69Ju6?p=preview . I am just setting the productDetail value rather than making an http call, but otherwise I think this is essentially the code you wrote. I did one version with a default value, and the other without. What behavior are you expecting/wanting that isn't happening? What should be displayed in the child scope before the callApi() is called and resolved?

Comment: so in my child scope, I have something like var desc = $scope.$parent.productDetail.product[0].desc. It gave me can't find property of desc error because there is nothing in the productDetail yet and I have multiple objects returned from the calls

Comment: I believe you'll receive this error whether you're in the parent or child scope. You are trying to grab a property of non-existant object, so it's going to throw an error irrespective of the scope. If you check for existence of the $scope.$parent.productDetail before trying to access it's components, you'll avoid this. I don't think this has anything to do with parent/child scopes. Try putting that same code in the parent controller and I believe you'll get the same error.

Comment: You could also inject $q and create your own promise at the beginning of the call and save it off on $scope. Then you could resolve it after the data is set at the end. The child scope could then have a $scope.$parent.callPromise.then() where you could put logic that you don't want run until after everything resolves.